# Is there any way to speed up many instance of TravelDistance

Tags: curated-data, geography

The goal of this code is to identify and graph a "circle of cities" about a center city.

```
cityCenter = Interpreter["City"]["St. Louis"]
stateCenter = Interpreter["USState"]["Missouri"]
nearbyStates = 
 Join[AdministrativeDivisionData[Interpreter["USState"][stateCenter], 
   "BorderingStates"], {stateCenter}]
distanceToCenter[s_] := 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  TravelDistance[Interpreter["City"][cityCenter], 
   Interpreter["City"][s]]]
cityList = 
  Sort[Flatten[
    Table[CityData[{All, nearbyStates[[k]][[2]][[1]], 
       "UnitedStates"}], {k, 1, Length[nearbyStates]}]]];
table1 = Table[{cityList[[k]], distanceToCenter[cityList[[k]]]}, {k, 
    Length[cityList]}];
radius = 50;
tolerance = 0.05;

table2 = Join[{Interpreter["City"][cityCenter]}, 
   Select[table1, 
    radius*(1 - tolerance) <= #[[2]] <= radius*(1 + tolerance) &]];

graph1 = GeoListPlot[(First /@ table2), PlotMarkers -> Point, 
   GeoLabels -> Automatic, GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.5], 
   ImageSize -> Medium, GeoStyling["StreetMapLabels"]];
Drop[(First /@ table2), 1]
Length@(First /@ table2)
graph2 = GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[Interpreter["City"][cityCenter]]];
Show[graph1, graph2]
```

This seems unnecessarily slow (i.e., there is something better).  What's wrong? Is it the TravelDistance?

Comment: The poor performance is all the Interpreter[...] stuff and getting the CityData over the network. I even get a timeout error: `EntityValue::timeout: A network operation for EntityValue timed out. Please try again later.` The variable `cityList` is huge - I ended up with 6469 cities for `Length[cityList]` - most of the time spent in a runtime profile was  just downloading the data.

Comment: It runs as mine as-is.  Odd!

Comment: As a side note, it's possible to run your own instance of Graphhopper and query that without any restrictions or network issues (after a long setup time to build the graph). Graphhopper is almost certainly what WRI are using under the hood. It's a pity it seems impossible to point TravelDistance etc to a different instance.

Answer (score 2):

As flinty said, most of the time is required to download data. There are a couple of changes that will help that problem: 1) get `CityData` only for states near `cityCenter`, and 2) use [`TravelDistanceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TravelDistanceList.html) instead of `TravelDistance`.

If we test fewer cities, the process will be faster. We can limit the number of cities (and make fewer calls to `CityData`) by selecting the states with boundaries close to `cityCenter`. Here's how to  to select the states.

```
nearbyStates = Select[
   Join[AdministrativeDivisionData[stateCenter,
     "BorderingStates"], {stateCenter}], 
   QuantityMagnitude@
      GeoDistance[cityCenter, #, DistanceFunction -> "Boundary"] < 
     radius*(1 + tolerance) &];
```

For St. Louis and `radius` = 50, we call `CityData` for two states instead of nine.

Next, we need to get distances more efficiently because network calls are the slowest part of the task. `TravelDistance` needs 1 network call for each distance it finds. For me, finding the distances ran for more than 15 minutes.

Instead, a call to `TravelDistanceList` returns the all the distances between every pair of locations in a list. We can get many distances with one network call. I found the task was complete in less than 4 minutes.

However, `TravelDistanceList` doesn't accept long lists of locations (250 seems to work), so the list of cities must be grouped into "edible" chunks. `TravelDistanceList` returns distances between pairs of locations (saved as `distList`), but we need only the odd-numbered results. Combine `cityList` with the odd-numbered distances, and group each city and its distance as `table1`.

Here's the code to limit `nearbyStates` and use `TravelDistanceList`. I've simplified calls to `Interpreter[...]`, and changed the code for `cityList` and `table1`.

```
cityCenter = Interpreter["City"]["St. Louis"];
stateCenter = 
  cityCenter[EntityProperty["City", "AdministrativeDivision"]];
radius = 50;
tolerance = 0.05;
(*remove states if cityCenter is too far from a state's border*)
nearbyStates = Select[
   Join[AdministrativeDivisionData[stateCenter,
     "BorderingStates"], {stateCenter}], 
   QuantityMagnitude@
      GeoDistance[cityCenter, #, DistanceFunction -> "Boundary"] < 
     radius*(1 + tolerance) &];
(*distanceToCenter isn't needed, but it's useful for checking results*)
distanceToCenter[s_] := 
   QuantityMagnitude[TravelDistance[cityCenter, s]]
cityList = Sort[Flatten[
    CityData[{All, ##}] & @@@ 
     EntityValue[nearbyStates, "CanonicalName"]]];
distList = QuantityMagnitude[
   TravelDistanceList /@ Partition[
     Riffle[ConstantArray[cityCenter, Length[cityList]], cityList],
     UpTo[250]]
   ];
table1 = Partition[
   Riffle[cityList, 
    Flatten[#[[Range[1, Length[#], 2]]] & /@ distList]],
   2];
table2 = Join[{cityCenter}, 
   Select[table1, 
    radius*(1 - tolerance) <= #[[2]] <= radius*(1 + tolerance) &]];
graph1 = GeoListPlot[First /@ Rest[table2], PlotMarkers -> Point,
      GeoLabels -> Automatic, GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.5],
      ImageSize -> Medium, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMap"]];
graph2 = GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[cityCenter]];
Show[graph1, graph2]
```